# Replace values of rows based on a condition and an input parameter

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop, scipy

If I have a table- similar to what you see below. How can I write a for loop that iterates between only columns 2-8 and would look at the input parameter and based on the condition specified in the for loop, replace the values in each row.

For example, if the input parameter is input=40, I would like to write a for loop that if it finds a value >= that input parameter in columns 2-8, then their values would be replaced by the input parameter. If the values are less  than or equal to the input parameter, then the row values would remain the same.

If there are other methods to handle this, please feel free to share it. However, I want the output to populate all rows in specified columns.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should work. This should only change the columns in the columns list that are greater than or equal to the number variable. Hope this helps! (need to import numpy as np)

```
number = 5
columns = ['col1','col2']
df[columns] = np.where(df[columns]>=number,number,df[columns])
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this should work, but I get the following error:  ```"None of [Index(['2020-12-31', '2021-03-31'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"```

Comment: Check to see if your columns have spaces on either side (or both sides). For example ' col1' instead of 'col1'

Comment: Did either of these solutions answer your question?

Comment: Yes, they did. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome! Please see link on how to close out a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Its similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29020132/11958218)

```
num=40

#where(condition, new value) replace the values where condition is False
df.loc[:, 'Col2':'Col8']= df.loc[:, 'Col2':'Col8'].where(df.loc[:, 'Col2':'Col8'] < num, num)
```

However if you have column positions instead of column names you can replace `df.loc[:, 'Col2':'Col8']` by `df.iloc[:,[1,7]]` which takes 2nd column to 8th column

## Example

```
d={'Col1':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
    'Col2':[132, 93, 124, 475, 857, -46, 67],
    'Col3':[234, 123, 765, 1452, 542, 2562, 5876],
    'Col4':[7, 7 ,4 , 5 , 1, 9,3]}
data=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

```
print(data)
    Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
0     1   132   234     7
1     2    93   123     7
2     3   124   765     4
3     4   475  1452     5
4     5   857   542     1
5     6   -46  2562     9
6     7    67  5876     3
```

replacing any values >=500 in Col2 to Col3 by 500

```
data.loc[:, 'Col2':'Col3']=data.loc[:, 'Col2':'Col3'].where(data.loc[:, 'Col2':'Col3'] < 500, 500)
```

After updating, replacing any values >=500 in Col2 to Col3 by 500

```
print(data)
    Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
0     1   132   234     7
1     2    93   123     7
2     3   124   500     4
3     4   475   500     5
4     5   500   500     1
5     6   -46   500     9
6     7    67   500     3
```